# How do you group together validation messages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have this model in mvc with various validation attributes all of which provide error messages

```
 public class Images
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int ImageId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter your first name")]
        public string SubmitterFirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your surname name")]
        public string SubmitterLastName { get; set; }
        [ExistingFileName]
        public string NameOfImage { get; set; }
        [StringLength(140, ErrorMessage="Please reduce the length of your description to below 140 characters")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string DescriptionOfImage { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }
```

Each of these error messages appear to the side of the (in this case) text boxes they are validating, is there are way to group them all together in a view with say a `<div>`?
Such as:

```
<div id="errorMessages">
//Errors appear here
<div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple actually. Use below in your view inside the form element:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Form validation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")
```

Note that the initial Boolean argument that you pass as `false` is for the `excludePropertyErrors` parameter, which will obviously include the individual property errors in the [validation summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary.aspx) if it is set to false.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ValidationSummary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.validationextensions.validationsummary%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to place all error messages in one place

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(...)
```